# Serialization issue with XmlElement [ ]

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

I am trying to add few items to XElementArray [] which is a part of wcf request object.

In the generated proxy class the property is defined as

```
private XmlElement[] MetaData;
```

Am adding element to this xelement array as below

```
XmlElement[] MetaDataDoc = new XmlElement[10];
string fileName = string.Empty;
var xmldocm = new XmlDocument();
xmldocm.Load(fileName);
MetaDataDoc = xmldocm.DocumentElement.ChildNodes.Cast<XmlElement>().ToArray();
```

If i add a breakpoint i could see only the child nodes are added  to the array . Am then setting this MeteDataDoc to MetaData property of wcf request

Here is the sample xml which i loaded to add elements to xmlarray

```
 <DocumentTemplate>
   <MetaData>
   <FileName>Account Details</FileName>
   <Description>Account Details</Description>
   <Language>English - US</Language>
   <BusinessChannel>
   <Inbound>true</Inbound>
   </BusinessChannel>
   </MetaData>
</DocumentTemplate>
```

But when wcf serializes the request its coming like below...adding the MetaData node multiple times..and adding elements under that .

Not adding element under  single MetaData node

```
<MetaData>
  <FileName>Account Details</FileName>
</MetaData>
<MetaData>
  <Description>Account Details</Description>
</MetaData>
<MetaData>
  <Language>English - US</Language>
</MetaData>
<MetaData>
  <BusinessChannel>
    <Inbound>true</Inbound>
  </BusinessChannel>
</MetaData>
```

Please could you help me out to resolve this issue

Comment: I don't see any code related to WCF. How about posting a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) example

Comment: I have modified it.tnx